# DC Analysis of Transistor Circuits - Double vertical line symbol

Tags: math, analysis, math-notation

I have stumbled twice across this symbol `||` being used in the analysis of transistor circuits.

An example can be seen at this address: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Dc-analysis-of-a-bipolar-junction-transistor-circuit

[image]

I can understand it: `x||y = (xy)/(x+y)`

But what is it called and why is it used? Because I do not know the name, I was unable to find anything with a search. "Double vertical line transistor circuit analysis" didn't return any results.

Comment: It's shorthand for "in parallel with"

Comment: Do note \$ a || b || ... || z = 1 / ( \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + ... \frac{1}{z} )\$. In case of **only** x and y it can be rewritten to (xy) / (x+y)

Comment: To avoid confusion: In case of only **2 variables** it can be rewritten to (xy) / (x+y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shorthand for "in parallel with", though I've never seen it used before and it's certainly not an accepted mathematical operator.

In many programming languages that would be a logical OR operator.

Comment: I think i first came across the notation in some TI literature about opamps, no idea where it comes from though.

Comment: When I first encountered it I thought it was an or operator, but couldn't understand what the meant in the context of a circuit. It makes sense that it means "parallel". I guess this isn't a standard notation then?

Comment: Actually, does that make sense? Working through the content on that webpage I find myself completely confused. What does `Rb` refer to?

Comment: The **parallel operator** || is a **mathematical function** which is used especially as shorthand in electrical engineering. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(operator)

Comment: I have used it for as long as I can remember (~30 yrs). But it is a human shorthand, I don't know of any programming languages that recognize it as parallel.

Comment: A quick Google search for "parallel operator" suggests that it's a long way from being universally recognised.